# Ionic 3 facebook login

Tags: angular, facebook, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a facebook login for my Ionic 3 app - all has been working well with no problems, however out of nowhere it no longer works.

My welcome.ts file

```
loginWithFacebook() {
   this.loading = true;
   this.userService.loginWithFacebook().then((success) => {
      let profile = success.additionalUserInfo.profile;
      console.log('Successfully')
}
```

My User provider file

```
loginWithFacebook(){
   if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      console.log('Mobile login');
      return this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
         console.log('entered facebook login code');
         const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
            .credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
            return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
     });
  } else {
       console.log('Web login');
       return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
}
```

}

In Chrome, the function works perfectly, but when built and ran on my iPhone, it will never reach then 'then' part in the welcome.ts file, it just wont run the code within in.

Am I missing something that is different when this is ran on a device?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to a different page after logging in with Facebook?

Comment: I was, however even when I changed the code to the above, it still isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Firebase to your iOS app? If you haven't already: log in to your Firebase console, open your project settings and choose Add Firebase to Your iOS App.

Download `GoogleService-Info.plist` config file and copy it to these paths of your project: `project_name/platforms/ios/project_name/resources` and `project_name/platforms/ios/project_name/resources/resources`.

Run `ionic cordova build ios` and try to run your app again.

Comment: Yes mate - I stated that everything had been working absolutely fine until it stopped out of nowhere

Comment: Can you help me please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828673/i-can-not-authenticate-myapp-with-facebook-from-ios?noredirect=1#comment88663516_50828673 I have a similar problem..