# I can not authenticate myapp with facebook from ios

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I follow the official documentation of the plugin: `cordova-plugin-facebook4` and the only thing I have to do is get the id of my application and the name from`facebook developers`:

[image: enter the description of the image here]

and execute the command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID = "380 ....." --variable APP_NAME = "TI...."
```

for `android` I have this configuration:

[image: enter the description of the image here]

I managed to get the `key hash` and it works. but for it to work I had to edit this file:

```
platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml
```

and I added these lines (If I do not add these lines, it does not work):

```
<string name = "fb_app_id">380...</ string>
<string name = "fb_app_name">TI...</ string>
```

it works like this:, any user can authenticate by facebook, but strangely am, I was the developer, I asked for the key `hash generated`, if I do not add it, it allows authenticating any user except me, therefore I added the`key hash` . (But I do not care because it works for me)

So I have the configuration for `ios`:

[image: enter the description of the image here]

To try to prove it I am using a virtual machine of `mac` and use`xcode` to compile and test my application, but when I try to click on the authentication button on Facebook, the web browser opens with a facebook web page (I do not have the app), with this error:

in english:

```
the identifier of the application is not valid. the indicated identifier does not look like a valid application identifier
```

[image: enter the description of the image here]

in `Android` I do the same procedure, I do not have the facebook app and the web browser is loaded with facebook, I authenticate and redirects to my app once authenticated. in `IOs` it does not work.

this is shown by the `XCODE` console:

[image: enter the description of the image here]

What I can do?
this is my config.xml

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have look in your `config.xml`, you `APP_ID` is most probably misspelled. The variable there should look like `<variable name="APP_ID" value="999999999999999" />`

Comment: @DavidDalBusco I value a lot that you answered. I have updated the question by attaching my config.xml

Comment: Looks ok then. Maybe remove add your platform again or double check that you did the all config in your facebook administration console, see for example that tutorial https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-facebook-login

Comment: @DavidDalBusco I looked over the link and I do not see anything different from what I have done. I will try to eliminate the platform but I do not think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See the Android Guide of the plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/android/README.md chapter **cordova-android >= 7**

According the screenshot of your config, the configuration for your cordova-android 7 is missing

```
<config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
    <string name="fb_app_id">123456789</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">myApplication</string>
</config-file>
```

Comment: Thanks! But on decices android works for me. My problem is on ios devices..

Comment: Ok I've got no other ideas if all your config is correct. Good luck